# Accessing Makefile variable in compile time shell

Tags: shell, makefile, gnu-make

I have a makefile, 1.mk with following content:

```
#!make

aa := x
bb := y
cc := z

export
include abc.mk

all:
    @echo $(chk1)
```

And another makefile, abc.mk with following content:

```
#!make

chk1 := $(shell set -o posix; set | awk -F "=" 'BEGIN{ORS=" "}1 $$1~/[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*/ {print $$1}')
chk2 := $(shell env &> pqr)

export
```

When I check, none has the makefile-variables:

```
> make all -f 1.mk | grep aa

> grep 'aa' pqr
```

Thus I can say, compile time shell does not have makefile variables. I want a way to access all makefile variables in compile-time shell.

Constraint: I do not know variable names beforehand to write code in following manner:

```
chk2 := $(shell export aa=$(aa); env &> pqr)
```

Comment: What you ask for is not 100% clear to me. What do you mean by "_I want "xyz.sh" to have all makefile variable_"? Do you want to (manually) define all your makefile variables in a file named `xyz.sh`? And what does "_I need to evaluate it at compile time_" mean? What compilation? Do you mean that you want to import the variable definitions from `xyz.sh` when make parses the makefile?

Comment: I agree that the question is unclear.  If what you're saying is that you want the shell script `xyz.sh` to have access to the make variables `a`, `b`, and `c`, then you can add an `export a b c` before you run the script, and those make variables will be exported into the environment and the shell script can access them as environment variables `$a`, `$b`, `$c`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have updated the question. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the way make exports make variables, it does so only in recipes, not in the shells invoked with the `shell` function. You can test this with, for instance:

```
$ cat Makefile
aa := x
export
chk := $(shell echo $$aa)

.PHONY: all

all:
    @printf 'in shell function: aa = $(chk)\n'
    @printf 'in recipe:         aa = %s\n' "$$aa"

$ make
in shell function: aa = 
in recipe:         aa = x
```